# Firebug shows "offset" as Outer displacement ring enclosing Margin, Border, Padding, Element

Tags: html, firebug

In Firebug's HTML Layout view, what HTML property does "offset" represent. I have goggled around looking for a coherent answer and have yet to find one.

Answer (score 2):

Below is what I think it is:

`offset` of an element (in this Firebug context) refers to its position within its immediate parent container.

Read [Firebug and CSS Layout](http://getfirebug.com/layout.html)

I quote:
**Measure each edge**

Firebug's Layout tab gives you a visual breakdown of each box in the box model and the width of each each edge. Additionally, it shows you the width and height of the innermost box, and the x and y **offset** of the element relative to its parent.

[image: Screen Layout Edge]

(Image courtesy of http://getfirebug.com)